# How to run the video after the if statement in python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I've created a code to detect fire in video using OpenCV and the technique is using the HSV color space to detect the color and flag an alarm but the problem is when the alarm starts the video window stop or it doesn't show from the beginning of the program. Can someone please help?

The alarm and video can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KWbiNbgmNWdeqR2bV5hJiQ3ugPWx-0Fe/view?usp=sharing)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import playsound

Alarm_Status = False

def play_sound():
    playsound.playsound("Alarm Sound.mp3",True)

# Importing the video
cam = cv2.VideoCapture("Fire.mp4")

while True:
    # Reading the camera
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    
    # Converting the color to HSV
    hsv_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    
    # Set the color boundaries
    lower = np.array([18, 50, 50], dtype = "uint8")
    upper = np.array([35, 255, 255], dtype = "uint8")
    
    # Color detection
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_frame, lower, upper)
    
    # Create the Output video
    output = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, hsv_frame, mask = mask)
    
    # Count the number of red pixels
    redPixels = cv2.countNonZero(mask)
    
    if int(redPixels) > 1000 and Alarm_Status == False:
        playsound()
        Alarm_Status = True
        pass
    
    # Showing the video
    cv2.imshow("Output", output)
    
    # Stoping the code
    if cv2.waitKey(25) == ord("q"):
        break
        
# Destroy the window
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cam.release()
```

Comment: `playsound.playsound` will block until the sound is finished playing.  You probably want to launch that in a thread.

Comment: Can you please show me how to add that thread to the code? I'm not familiar with thread in python.

Comment: Come on, it's all in the documentation, and there are lots of tutorials.  You have to apply some effort yourself.  `threading.Thread(target=play_sound, daemon=True).start()`

Comment: I know how to add threading but the problem is that I did it before and it didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

You can start the alarm in other process. Create `alarm.py` file:

```
import playsound
playsound.playsound("Alarm Sound.mp3",True)
```

in your main app you can call `alarm.py`:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import playsound
import subprocess
Alarm_Status = False


# Importing the video
cam = cv2.VideoCapture("Fire.mp4")

while True:
    # Reading the camera
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    
    # Converting the color to HSV
    hsv_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    
    # Set the color boundaries
    lower = np.array([18, 50, 50], dtype = "uint8")
    upper = np.array([35, 255, 255], dtype = "uint8")
    
    # Color detection
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_frame, lower, upper)
    
    # Create the Output video
    output = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, hsv_frame, mask = mask)
    
    # Count the number of red pixels
    redPixels = cv2.countNonZero(mask)
    
    if int(redPixels) > 1000 and Alarm_Status == False:
        subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/python3","./alarm.py"])
        Alarm_Status = True
        pass
    
    # Showing the video
    cv2.imshow("Output", output)
    
    # Stoping the code
    if cv2.waitKey(25) == ord("q"):
        break
        
# Destroy the window
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cam.release()
```